# Solve limit with square root signs

Tags: limits

I have an homework question that I can't solve. Solve the following limit: 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\;(x^2+3)^\frac {1}{2}\ - (x^2 + x)^\frac {1}{2}\  
$$

Comment: Do you mean find $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}(x^2+3)^\frac {1}{2}\ - (x^2 + x)^\frac {1}{2} \; $??

Comment: Yes I forgot to add limit to infinity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $x\in D=(-\infty,-1]\cup[0,\infty)$ we have
$$
f(x):=\sqrt{x^2+3}-\sqrt{x^2+x}=\frac{(x^2+3)-(x^2+x)}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}=\frac{3-x}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3-x}{\sqrt{x^2+3}+\sqrt{x^2+x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{3}{x}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{3}{x}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}}=-\frac12.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\root{x^{2} + 3} - \root{x^{2} + x}
=
{\pars{\root{x^{2} + 3} - \root{x^{2} + x}}\pars{\root{x^{2} + 3} + \root{x^{2} + x}} \over \root{x^{2} + 3} + \root{x^{2} + x}}
\\[3mm]&=
{\pars{x^{2} + 3} - \pars{x^{2} + x} \over \root{x^{2} + 3} + \root{x^{2} + x}}
=
-\,{x - 3 \over \root{x^{2} + 3} + \root{x^{2} + x}}
=
-\,{1 - 3/x \over \root{1 + 3/x^{2}} + \root{1 + 1/x}}
\end{align}

> $$
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{\root{x^{2} + 3} - \root{x^{2} + x}}
> =
> \lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{-\,{1 - 3/x \over \root{1 + 3/x^{2}} + \root{1 + 1/x}}}
> =-\,{1 \over 1 + 1}
> $$

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{\root{x^{2} + 3} - \root{x^{2} + x}}
=
-\,\half}$$